# Como manipular dados de um fragment ao deslizar para o proximo?

Tags: android

Explicando:

Tenho 3 fragments em um viewpager2, para que faça slides.

Em um fragment especifico, tenho alguns dados em edittext e etc. Ao deslizar para o proximo fragment, preciso que estes dados sejam gravados ou manipulados de alguma forma. Mas o botão próximo ou a propria açao de slide, é feito na activity ou viewpager2. Como ter os textos dos edittexts manipulados após esta açao?

Aqui é minha activity que instancia os fragments:

```
public class ScreenSlideActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private ViewPager2 mPager;
    private FragmentStateAdapter pagerAdapter;
    private Button btn_pular;
    private Button btn_voltar;
    ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_slide);

        btn_pular = findViewById(R.id.btn_puler_pager);
        btn_voltar = findViewById(R.id.btn_voltar_pager);

        // Instantiate a ViewPager and a PagerAdapter.
        mPager = findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(this, initiateFragments());
        mPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        mPager.setPageTransformer(new ZoomOutPageTransformer());

    }

    private ArrayList<Fragment> initiateFragments() {

        fragments.add(ScreenSlidePageFragment1.newInstance());
        fragments.add(ScreenSlidePageFragment2.newInstance());
        fragments.add(ScreenSlidePageFragment3.newInstance());

        return fragments;
    }


    public void onClickBtn_pular(View view) {

        mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);

    }

    public void onClickVoltar(View view){
        onBackPressed();
    }
    private void compartilha(){

    }

    private void gravaItems(){

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
            // If the user is currently looking at the first step, allow the system to handle the
            // Back button. This calls finish() on this activity and pops the back stack.
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            // Otherwise, select the previous step.
            mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Aqui meu fragment, o primeiro na lista:

```
public class ScreenSlidePageFragment1 extends Fragment {

    private GravaItems gravaItems;
    private Button btn;

    public static ScreenSlidePageFragment1 newInstance(){

        return new ScreenSlidePageFragment1();
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page1, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

seu layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/appCompatImageView1"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView19"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textNome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="228dp"
        android:text="Nome:"
        android:textColor="@color/verde_escuro"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/edtNome"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtNome"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:hint="Digite seu nome"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/cinza"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textNome" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTelefone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Telefone:"
        android:textColor="@color/verde_escuro"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/edtNome"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edtNome" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edttelefone"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
        android:hint="(31) 91234-1234"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/cinza"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textTelefone" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

E aqui, meu viewpager2:

```
public class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private FragmentActivity fa;

    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentActivity fa, ArrayList<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fa);
        this.fa = fa;
        this.fragments = fragments;

    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }
```

Como passar ao proximo fragment e ter os os textos dos edittexts ,gravados ou manipulados, nesta açao? Obrigado

Comment: Existem várias alternativas. Uma delas é acessando um método (público) do seu fragmento desejado através da  `ScreenSlideActivity`. Outra é armazenar em Local Storage, o que não parece fazer sentido no seu caso se eu entendi direito. Pode até mesmo usar uma classe estática pra isso, mas não acho uma boa ideia.

Comment: resolvi com sharedpreferences, achei mais rapido, se quiser responder de um jeito melhor, marco como resposta